# How to set the cursor inside a newly added empty span with Javascript (in a contenteditable div)?

Tags: javascript, contenteditable

I have a contenteditable div that has formatting options. I would like to be able to click on, say the bold button, and insert `<span class="bold">` and `</span>` to the left and right of my cursor respectively.  I believe I have managed to do this. However, I do not know how to place the cursor inside the span so that the user might start typing in bold text.

The function I am currently working with:

```
function bold(text,clearSelection) {
    text = text.replace(/\r\n/g,"<br>");
    var sel, range, html;
    var tn = false;
    //Here i am adding the span element
    if (window.getSelection) {
        sel = window.getSelection();
        if (sel.getRangeAt && sel.rangeCount) {
            range = sel.getRangeAt(0);
            range.deleteContents();
            tn = document.createElement("span");
            tn.className="bold";
            tn.innerHTML=text;
            range.insertNode(tn);           
        }
    }
    if(clearSelection){
        //if the selection length is longer than 0, move cursor to end of selection
        if(sel.toString().length >0){
            range = window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0);
            range.setStart(range.endContainer,range.endOffset);
            document.getElementById('text').focus();
        } else {  
            /*Do something if the selection length is zero to place the cursor inside the span?*/
        }
    }
}
```

Edit: The following ended up working

```
if(clearSelection){
    //if the selection length is longer than 0, move cursor to end of selection
    if(sel.toString().length >0){
        range = window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0);
        range.setStart(range.endContainer,range.endOffset);
        document.getElementById('text').focus();
    } else {
        if(tn!==false){
            range.selectNodeContents(tn);
            document.getElementById('text').focus();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: PS: You have some problems with your bracket hierachies which make it more complicated to read and understand your code.

Comment: You won't be able to place the caret inside an empty span in WebKit or IE. You'll need some kind of hack, such as inserting a zero-width space inside the span and selecting it. For example, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14347462/set-caret-position-in-contenteditable-div and http://stackoverflow.com/a/14104166/96100

Comment: What is the `if (window.getSelection)` conditional for?

Answer (score 2):

There is no fiddle to try but how about placing var tn = ... above first if statement and then use focus() on it, like

```
var tn = false;
if (window.getSelection) {
    sel = window.getSelection();
    if (sel.getRangeAt && sel.rangeCount) {
...
        tn = document.createElement("span");
...          
    }
}
if(clearSelection){
    if(sel.toString().length >0){

    } else {
    /*Do something if the selection length is zero to place the cursor inside the span?*/
        if (tn !== false) {
            tn.focus();
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: This was on the right track. I ended up with the following, which works:

if(tn!==false){
    range.selectNodeContents(tn);
    document.getElementById('text').focus();
}